# Do we need explicit for CTOR with pointer type?

Tags: c++, explicit, explicit-constructor

Do we need `explicit` in this case:

```
class A
{
    explicit A(B* b);
};
```

I think that even if we do not mark the constructor as `explicit`, it will be a compilation error to write:

```
A a = new B();
```

Implicit conversion from pointer to an object is not possible via a constructor at all, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will fail to compile Conversion will fail from `B*` to `A`.

This is exactly the kind of thing the explicit will prevent.

You should just write `A a( new B() );` in this case or if you want to be real verbose you could write `A a = A( new B() );`

As to the root question: do you need it or not that's up to you and your team.  Generally a main question is : are you ever going to have an 'int' constructor ( will lead to amibiguity with * types ), what do you want to happen, and do you want implicit conversions to happen from construction arguments or not.

Comment: The top of my answer was written for what to do if you DID use `explicit` keyword.  Without `explicit` you can do what you did above and it won't be an error.

Answer (score 1):

You *do* need the `explicit` if you do not want that constructor to be usable for implicit conversions. It is perfectly possible to have a constructor-based implicit conversion accepting a pointer.

Comment: What are the cases that will compile if remove `explcit`. For example `A a = new B(); ` cannot be compile even if there is no `explicit` there.

Comment: `A a = new B();` **will** compile, if there's no `explicit` in the constructor (and the constructor is accessible at that point of code, of course).

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need explicit for CTOR with pointer type?

It depends on you and your team, if you are working in a team. It's more of a coding guideline than anything else. The language doesn't mandate it.

Comment: You mean, I am write and compiler will catch conversion with error anyways, right?

Comment: It sounds like @UpAndAdam says `A a = new B(); ` is normal without `explicit` and you say it will not compile even if there is not `explicit`.

Comment: @Narek, no, I am not saying that. What UpAndAdam says is correct.